# How to use fscanf and fgets from a text file with ints and strings?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

Example file:

```
School Name (with spaces)
FirstNameofStudent StudentID
School Name2 (with spaces)
FirstNameofStudent2 StudentID2
School Name3 (with spaces)
FirstNameofStudent3 StudentID3
```

I cant seem to figure out what to do after using fgets for the first line.

If by itself, I can easily get school name using `fgets`
and the second line by itself using `fscanf` then converting the `studentID` to int using `atoi`.

But how do I combine both `fgets` and `fscanf`?

The information scanned would be placed into an array.

Comment: What problem are you have calling `fscanf()` after `fgets()`? Also, you could just `fgets()` all lines, then use `sscanf()` on the strings for lines with multiple fields.

Comment: [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Wait, do you want a command that both reads a line, AND formats it? Isn't that `fscanf` already? Unless you just want a way to place the information in an array of strings?

Comment: "by itself, I can easily get school name using fgets and the second line by itself using fscanf" --> post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Before I go onto the solution, I want to point out that an array can only have a single type. You cannot store integers in an array of characters.

Meaning if you would like all of this information to go in a single 2D array, you'd need to store the ID as a string. Then if you need it as an integer, you'd need to use `atoi` on it once you retrieve it.

Now for combining the two, you'd need a while loop with `fgets` in the condition in order to retrieve the first line. Something like this:

```
while(fgets(schoolname, 255, fp) != 0){ ... }
```

This would keep on retrieving lines until it fails, or it reaches EOF. However, you wanted to use `fscanf` for the second line, and for that, you'd need a line like this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s\n", name, id);
```

This means, from the current point, there are two strings seperated by a space, and a newline. Store the two strings in `name` and `id`, and gobble the newline.

Gobbling the newline is key, as if you don't do it, the next time `fgets` runs, it would only find a single newline on the line.

As for storing the elements in an array, you'd need a 2D array of strings. For that, you can either do it fixed, or dynamic. For fixed, it's pretty easy, just have a line like `char students[3][3][80]` and simply store stuff in there, but for dynamic, you'd need to use memory allocation, pointers, etc, with a variable liks `char ***students`

Here's the code I used to solve your problem, though I suggest trying to do this on your own as well, to get the hang of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("ex.txt", "r");

    if(fp == 0) exit(-1);

    char ***students;

    // Used to check how many students there are
    int studentno = 0;

    // Init students array
    // So far it means 1 ROW, with 3 COLUMNS, each of 80 CHARACTERS
    students = calloc(studentno+1, 3 * 80);

    // Temporary variables for storage
    char schoolname[80];
    char name[20];
    char id[10];

    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(schoolname, 255, fp) != 0){
        studentno++;

        // Retrieve name and id from second line
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s\n", name, id);

        // Cut off newline left from fgets
        schoolname[strlen(schoolname)-2] = 0;

        // Allocate memory for new members of array
        students[i] = malloc(3 * 80);
        students[i][0] = malloc(80);
        students[i][1] = malloc(80);
        students[i][2] = malloc(80);

        // Copy strings received into array
        strcpy(students[i][0], schoolname);        
        strcpy(students[i][1], name);
        strcpy(students[i][2], id);

        // Resize students array for additional students
        students = realloc(students, (size_t) (studentno+1) * 3*80);

        i++;
    }

    // Check students are stored correctly
    for(int i = 0; i < studentno-1; i++){
        printf("%s - %s - %s\n", students[i][0], students[i][1], students[i][2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That helps so much!

Comment: Lets say we have an unknown sized file.

Would it be easier to allocate the information from the file into a struct / linked list?

Comment: For an unknown sized file this would still work, as it works regardless of how large the file is. As for the other question, you could technically have an array of structs and remove the type limitation. Constructing linked lists is slightly harder than simply having an array of structs and `realloc`'ing every time you add.

Comment: regarding: `schoolname[strlen(schoolname)-2] = 0;`  this statement 'may' or 'may not' actually cutoff the newline.   To start, indexes in C start with 0 not 1 and the function: `strlen()` returns the index to the NUL byte at the end of the string.  So, at best, this statement will chop off both the newline and the character before the newline.  Suggest using: `schoolname[ strspn( schoolname, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  While assigning '0` may result in a character being replaced by 0x00 due to implied conversion, (which the `gcc` compiler will complain if using option: `-Wconversion`)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: You're definitely right - I only used `schoolname[strlen(schoolname)-2]` because after testing it seemed to be the right value. -1 ended up keeping the newline in. But that was more of a hack than a solution, I have to admit.